# Why is $f(z)= z^{1/2}$ not continuous on the negative real axis?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My complex analysis textbook claims that $f(z) = z^{1/2} = r^{1/2}cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) + ir^{1/2}sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$ , where $ r>0$,  and $-\pi<\theta \leq \pi$, and this means that $f$ is analytic at all points other than the origin and the negative real axis. The reasoning is that it is not continuous on the negative real axis. why is this?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1481406/28900).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\lim_{\theta\to\pi} f(e^{i\theta}) = \lim_{\theta\to\pi} e^{i\theta/2} = e^{i\pi/2} = i$

$\lim_{\theta\to-\pi} f(e^{i\theta}) = \lim_{\theta\to-\pi} e^{i\theta/2} = e^{-i\pi/2}=-i$

Comment: Thanks! at the origin though, $\theta$ can take any value , so why is it not continuous there?

Comment: @user3677952 It's continuous at the origin, but it's not analytic there.  If it were analytic at the origin, it would have to be continuous in some neighborhood of the origin.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x\to 0+}(-1+xi)^{1/2} =i$ and $\lim_{x\to 0+}(-1-xi)^{1/2}\to -i$.