# Making sense of $(-1)^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I just opened a [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195808/abc-and-abc-for-complex-numbers?noredirect=1#3195808) that sparked a new question that I now want to discuss (making a new thread however to not clog the other one).

Obviously looking at $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ one might have the number $i$ in mind. But as I've now learned defining complex powers has a pretty random aspect to it. So if I take a branch other than the principal branch of the logarithm, say $$L(Re^{i\varphi}):=\ln(R)+i\varphi+2\pi i,$$ I might as well write $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\exp(\frac{1}{2} L(-1))=\exp\left(\frac{3\pi i}{2}\right)$ which is completely different. Are my thoughts correct here? Is $e^{3\pi i/2}$ just another value that might be assigned to $(-1)^\frac{1}{2}$? And does this have any upside at all? What's the point of using different branches?

Comment: With $(-1)^{\frac 12}$, you want to find all numbers which, when squared, are equal to $-1$. The two numbers satisfying this property are $i$ and $-i$. And $e^{3\pi i/2} = -i$.

Comment: So writing $(-1)^\frac{1}{2}=i$ doesn't make any sense?

Comment: No it doesn't and i is written in that way only in elementary courses. In more advanced courses, we do something like this:  consider the set of all **pairs**, (x, y) ofreal numbers.  Define the sum of such pairs by (x, y)+ (u, v)= (x+ u, y+ v) and the product by (x, y)(u, v)= (xu- yv, uy+ xv).  It is easy to show that all the usual arithmetic laws apply- that this is a "field". It is also easy to show that the pairs of the form (x, 0) are isomorphic to the real numbers and that (0, 1)(0, 1)= (-1, 0).  We identify (1, 0) with 1 and (0, 1) with i so we can write (x, y)= x(1, 0)+ y(0, 1)= x+ iy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $A^B$ does not have a generally recognized definition that applies when $A=-1$ and $B=1/2$.

There are some fairly popular candidate definitions, though.

One is to consider that $A^B$ can be a **"multi-valued expression"** whose value can be every complex number that can be written as $\exp(Bz)$ where $z$ is a complex number that satisfies $\exp(z)=A$. According to this definition, the possible values of $(-1)^{1/2}$ are exactly $i$ and $-i$. Your $\exp(\frac{3\pi i}{2})$ happens to be one of these: it is equal to $-i$.

The trouble with this is that "multi-valued expression" is a confusing and sometimes ill-defined concept, and in particular the meaning of an *equality* between multi-valued expressions becomes very context-dependent ("it means whatever you need it to mean for what you're doing to make sense" is not really a good basis for rigorous reasoning). Depending on how you interpret the $=$, you could get $(-1)^{1/2}=i$ to be true or false or some kind of either/or. Not particularly enlightening.

A more careful and sophisticated way to handle the idea of "multi-valued" is **Riemann surfaces**. They are useful for giving a sensible meaning to ambiguous expressions that depend smoothly on some parameter -- but on the other hand doing it carefully means that simply writing down an expression such as $(-1)^{1/2}$ does not in itself point to a value. So it is not an answer to the immediate question.

A different definition would be to speak of the **principal value** of $A^B$, defined as $\exp(Bz)$ where $z$ is *the* particular solution of $\exp(z)=A$ whose imaginary part falls in the half-open interval $(-\pi,\pi]$. Then $(-1)^{1/2}=i$ becomes plain truth.

The trouble *now* is that the "principal part" operation lacks many of the nice properties we otherwise expect arithmetic operations to have. It is not continuous, for example. And the choice of $(-\pi,\pi]$ is pretty arbitrary. The definition at least gives the warm fuzzy feeling of having a definite answer to what the value of the expression is, but there's not much mathematical *utility* in having that answer.

And simply **refusing to define a value** for this expression seems to be at least as common as any of the above alternatives.

Comment: This is the only honest answer to this paradox, which comes up dozens of places on this site.  Every other thread has numerous responses, all explaining why the fallacy is _obviously_ wrong, yet each one giving a different "obvious" reason.  This is the only _honest_ answer: There isn't a really good candidate, let alone an agreed upon standard, for defining these expressions (as basic as their syntax may seem).