# Complex number under Sqrt

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it possible that $\sqrt{a+ i \: b} $ could not be written as one of the below forms?

$ i \sqrt{-a-i\:b} $

or

$-i \sqrt{-a-i\:b}$

$a$ and $b$ are real constants.

Comment: How do you define $\sqrt z$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It might be just me, but how are you saying that$$\sqrt{a+bi}=i\sqrt{-a-bi}$$And this question might be related to the common$$1=\sqrt{-1}\times\sqrt{-1}=i^2=-1$$fallacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set $$\sqrt{a+bi}=X+iY$$ and square it, then you will get
$$a+bi=X^2-Y^2+2XYi$$ and it must be $$a=X^2-Y^2,b=2XY$$ now you can calculate $$X,Y$$

Comment: Unclear answer!

Comment: why is my answer unclear?

Comment: Because it doesn't provide a yes or no to the question

Comment: Could you compute $$X,Y$$?

Comment: The question is if  $\sqrt{a+ib}$  equals $\pm i \sqrt{-a-ib}$, not if it can be written in the form $X+iY$.

Comment: when you compute $X,Y$ then you will see it!

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \sqrt{a+ i \: b}=\sqrt{-i^2(a+ i \: b)}=\sqrt{i^2} \cdot \sqrt{-(a+ i \: b)}=i\sqrt{-a-ib}$

Because: $\sqrt{i^2}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{-1})^2}=\sqrt{-1}=i$

**Update**: Thanks to Watson's comment as we can also find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481316/sqrtab-sqrta-sqrtb-for-complex-number-a-and-b?rq=1) we can't always separate the square roots but here we can.

If $|Arg(i^2)+Arg(a+ib)|≥π$, then $\sqrt{i^2 (a+ib)}=\sqrt {i^2} \sqrt {a+ib}$ does not hold,

but we have: $|Arg(i^2 \in \Bbb R)+Arg(a+ib)|=|0+Arg(a+ib)|=|Arg(z)|\leqπ$, So it is ok since always an argumnet of a complex number lies in the specified range.

Comment: It may not be possible to separate the sqrt to two parts

Comment: Why not? $\sqrt{fg}=(fg)^{1/2}=(f)^{1/2} \cdot (g)^{1/2}=\sqrt{f} \cdot \sqrt{g}$ @WatWatson

Comment: The are not real numbers

Comment: You can say $(fg)^{n}=f^n \cdot g^{n}$ for anything, do you have an example for opposite of this statement? @WatWatson

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481316/sqrtab-sqrta-sqrtb-for-complex-number-a-and-b?rq=1

Comment: You left a very interesting comment, thank you for that. but it is still ok, because: If $|Arg(i^2)+Arg(a+ib)|≥π$, then $\sqrt{i^2 (a+ib)}=\sqrt {i^2} \sqrt {a+ib}$ does not hold, but we have: $|Arg(i^2)+Arg(a+ib)|=|Arg(a+ib)|\leqπ$, So it is ok.Isnt' it? @WatWatson

Comment: I updated the answer @WatWatson